# If statement based on what boolean method returns

Tags: java, android, boolean

I am trying to use [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2403559) `boolean` method in my app. I want to use what it returns in an if statement so if it returns true I can do something. Something like

```
if(isNook() == True) {
   //do something
}
```

I'm sure the answer is obvious but I couldn't find anything on how to do this.

Comment: Your question is really, really unclear. Generally, all you have to do is say `if(isNook()) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are suggesting this:

```
if (isNook()) {
    // do something
}
```

which is correct. However, we need to discuss *your* attempt. This was it:

```
if(isNook() == True) {
   // do something
}
```

In Java, `boolean` variables are represented with `true` and `false` - NOT `True` and `False` - the values are case sensitive.

To contrast, for example, Python uses the values `True` and `False`

Your attempt should have been this:

```
if(isNook() == true) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use:

```
if (isNook()) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean bool_result;

if(bool_result = isNook( )) {
    // do stuff with bool_result here
}
```

result can actually be other data types (i.e. int/char/string) as long as it evaluates to true or false.

Comment: Please remove the last sentence, it is incorrect in Java.  Java _requires_ that the expression of an `if` must be a `boolean`.  It may not be an integer or any other type.  Other languages are more lenient about this.

Comment: Still no good.  An `int`/`char`/`string` cannot "evaluate to true or false".  You do realize that this question has a "java" tag, not "javascript", right?

Comment: What I was trying to say was something like: if((str = isNook( )) == "value") but wasn't sure of the wording. I understand what you are saying though.